# Necesito validar ingresos de multiplos de 100 por javascript, pero no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5

No me funciona el siguiente javascript, necesito ayuda

```
function validaMultiplos100(num)
{
    if (num % 100 == 0)
    {
        saldo.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    else
    {
        saldo.setCustomValidity("No es multiplo de 100");
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
<input type="number" oninput="validaMultiplos100(this)" class="form-control" id="saldo" name="saldo" required maxlength="50" />
                            <br />
                            <input type="hidden" value="DescontarSaldo" name="save">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Cargar</button>
```

Pero me sale esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Razor y asp.net mvc 5 son etiquetas que están demás

Comment: El código no está completo ya que no incluye la declaración de la variable saldo. Favor de ver [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si vas a dar soporte a navegadores nuevos, utiliza HTML5

```html
    <form>
      Cantidad mínimo: 100, sólo se permiten múltiplos de 100
      <br/>
      <input type="number" name="cantidad" min="100" step="100">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```